# I need a dialogue dataset

Tags: nlp, text

Where can I find a dataset of 2 people chit-chat dialogues? I need the data to be of full conversations, from "Hi" to "bye" so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [ParlAI](https://parl.ai/) framework, it is designed for dialogue researches.

The framework provides a set of [dialogue datasets](https://github.com/facebookresearch/ParlAI/blob/master/parlai/tasks/task_list.py). Please find those with tag "ChitChat" and see if they fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is to look around for "corpora" for text messages specifically.

I would recommend starting here: https://github.com/WING-NUS/nus-sms-corpus